# Docker api returns page not found

Tags: docker

Dockerd is running, but when I try to access the api I get file not found. What am I missing?

```
root@luna:/etc/systemd# ps -ef|grep dockerd
root       895     1  0 08:39 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
root      3768  3459  0 09:50 pts/2    00:00:00 grep dockerd

root@luna:/etc/systemd# curl --unix-socket /run/docker.sock http://info
{"message":"page not found"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have too many `/` in your http request url

When you're curling the unix socket, you only need a single `/`

So:

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/info
```